# Optimal elevator placement

Tags: probability, optimization

I was thinking about this in my building today.

Assume that the number of people trying to go up an elevator in a certain time period (say, an hour) is given by a Poisson distribution with mean $A$, and the number trying to go down is $B$. Assume the distribution of each passengers arrival time is uniform in the hour. Assume their are $n$ elevators.

Assume that, when not in service, each elevator immediately returns to a floor which is a function $f$ of the current position of all other elevators.

Assume that each elevator takes 15 sec between each floor and 30 sec each time it makes a stop.

Which function f described earlier mimimizes expected wait time for a passenger?

Comment: When in service, do the elevators follow the elevator algorithm?

Comment: No, they follow operator instructions. We should assume the building has $m$ floors, with passengers evenly distributed.

Comment: So does the operator follow the elevator algorithm (which is the most commonly used)? How does the elevator decide where to go and where to stop?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say passenger, not operator. If a passenger or passengers are in the elevator, it will stop at each floor that is pressed in order. Everyone is either going to or co i g from the bottom floor. When the elebstor is empty, it goes to a floor determined by f.

Comment: That's still insufficient to determine the behaviour. What happens if the elevator is going past a floor on which someone had pressed the button and was waiting for it? And as I asked earlier, to which floor does the elevator go if more than one person has pressed the button for it?

Comment: The elevator stops at every floor on which someone has selected a button. It behaves exactly as an ordinary elevator, except that it goes to a set floor after use. But I am interested in this as a real life problem, so if you can think of better conditions, I'd be interested in hearing them.

Comment: You still haven't fully described what happens if the elevator is empty and more than one floor has waiting passengers. In any case, your algorithm suffers from what is called starvation. (If you are on the top floor and the elevator is always busy and no one comes to the top floor, you'll never get it.) This is why in real life ordinary elevators use the elevator algorithm. (It does not change direction until it has serviced all requests possible in that direction, and it only picks up passengers going in the same direction. This is why you have both up and down buttons.)

Comment: It uses the elevator algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this problem does not have a specific solution. For starters, for high enough values of $A,B$ the expected wait time value is infinite regardless of $f$, since the mean service rate will be less than the mean arrival rate, and you haven't mentioned a floor capacity...not to mention that you haven't mentioned how you will control the total number of people. The mean value of the Poisson distributions should be dependent on the total population in the building.